# Simulate Save Image As

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I trigger a "Save Image As" action when an image is clicked?

Comment: @codefreak that question doesn't quite cover this one, because it assumes the image is already in URL form.

Comment: ok how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238545/how-to-save-an-image-via-javascript

Comment: Yup, that looks better. Although it seems that back then the possible solutions weren't as elegant.

Comment: +1 agreed :) download attribute is awesome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using HTML5's download attribute and no jQuery with:

```
<a href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" download>
    <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
</a>
```

You can also declare the filename if you would like it to take a name other than default:

```
<a href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" download="fileName.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
</a>
```

Comment: +1 - the download attribute rocks !

Comment: @j08691 I Tried this but its not working 
please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988259/download-image-on-click-in-a-preferred-name