# download image on click in a preferred name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save image on click, in a name that i want

I tried the solution suggested in a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079797/848841)

```
 <a href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" download="myPreferredName.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2881/10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
</a>
```

The problem that i am facing is, when i click on the image its downloading in the name **"10000610654_fdf29eb02f_q.jpg"** instead of **"myPreferredName.jpg"**

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buhw6c7j/)

I am ok to use javascript,jquery or any other scripting

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working

Comment: in firefox and IE its navigating to that image path :( not even downloading

Comment: Is the HTTP header Content-Disposition set? See the download attribute at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: IE does not use the `download` attribute ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)), so that's normal. But Firefox should if you set the right headers.

Comment: looks like it is not possible to overwrite the headers with preferred name in the download attribute