# How to export all images that got retrieve from HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to

- grab all the images from my website using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
- and export all of them to my Desktop `ALL` at once. ( `Not` right click save OR Screenshot )

**OPTIONAL**
- save all the `hyperlinks` into one nice text-file.

Here is what I have tried,

```
<?php include_once('/php/simple_html_dom.php'); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML DOM Parser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $html = file_get_html('http://my-website.com'); ?>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($html->find('img') as $img)

        <div id="pic" class="col-sm-1">
            {{$img}}
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the images to load, but I am not sure how to save them into my computer.
I am not sure even if it is possible.

Is there any php function or JS function that can do that ?

Comment: Right click on the pic -> Save To -> Desktop ? If you're only seeing URLs to the pics then use html <img> tag to display pics, then right click etc...

Comment: You could try [_How to save an image via Javascript_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238545/how-to-save-an-image-via-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

To save the URLs to a file, do something like this:

```
@foreach($html->find('img') as $img)
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $img."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); # this line saves URL to file
    <div id="pic" class="col-sm-1">
        {{$img}}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your code ` file_put_contents('file.txt', $img."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);` is adding links on my view- see [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d12o0ix62ambudw/links.JPG?dl=0) - and that is not what I want.